# Sed command and pattern space

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking at this script

`sed -i \   -e "s/^cluster_name.*/cluster_name: ${cluster_name}/g" \`

How is pattern space determined with ^ at the beginning and $ at the end?
Why do I need them?

Comment: `bash` replaces `${cluster_name}` with the content of the variable `cluster_name`.

Comment: @Cyrus But without ^,wouldn't be the same?

Comment: No, without `^` regex `cluster_name.*` could match `my_cluster_name`, too.

Comment: @MikiBelavista  The `^` "anchors" the match to the beginning of the line, only matching `cluster_name` if the line begins with it. Without it, and sed's "greediness" it may match a `cluster_name` anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^ and $ are regex operators. I am not aware of how these operators are implemented. But you need to use them when you want exact match from beginning of line or at the end of line.
e.g.
 Line1:     *This is line one.*
  -> starts with 'space' and ends with '.'
Line2:*This is dummy Line One*
 ->starts with 'T' and ends with 'e' characters.

if I am using regex as "^T.*e$" then it will match to line2.
[Please refer more information](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html)